# W/AudioGroup﹕ device loop timeout

Tags: java, android, sip

i'm trying to do a SIP call in my android. Sound works great on the first call, but when this call is ended and i start a second call, sound is interrupted and i get following warning (multiple lines per second):

> W/AudioGroup﹕ device loop timeout`

I start the call with:

```java
mSipManager.makeAudioCall(
    getAccount().getLocalSipProfile(),
    getAccount().getPeerSipProfile(),
    new SipCallListener(),
    0
);
```

Contents of call listener:

```
@Override
public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
    call.startAudio();
}

@Override
public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
    call.close();
}

// ...
```

Any idea how to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

// EDIT:
Currently i can reproduce this behaviour only on a Nexus 5 with Dalvik runtime. Changing the Runtime to ART "solves" the problem for this device, but it's not an acceptable solution.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case `startAudio()` was called twicely and I got `loop timeout`. So I left only one call to `startAudio()` outside `onCallEstablished()` and problem were solved. Target: Nexus 7. If you are still working on this problem just make a simpliest test and/or post your full code to describe this problem.

Comment: I am also seeing this log message multiple times, but I only have the one call to `startAudio()`. Is there anything else to look for?

Comment: I have no idea. Problem still unsolved.

Comment: For me, it doesn't always happen, and it only happens on Samsung devices, not Nexus ones.

Comment: In case anyone else is having this issue, I am still facing it on Samsung devices, but not just with SIP calls, but with RTP streams initiated without the SIP stack too. So far I still have no idea what causes it, although it seems to be worse in larger applications. Taking the code out into a "Hello World" type application fixes it.