# audiogroup device loop timeout on native android sip

Tags: android, cordova, sip

I am working on a Cordova plugin that uses the native android sip to make voip calls. It seems to be the same problem as [W/AudioGroup﹕ device loop timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803180/w-audiogroup-device-loop-timeout)

my SipAudioCall.Listener :

```
@Override
public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Call has been established");
    call.startAudio();
    call.setSpeakerMode(false);

    if (call.isMuted()) {
       call.toggleMute();
    }

    ServiceStatus status = getServiceStatus(call,
            call.getLocalProfile());
    SipPlugin.this.onSipEvent(status, "onCallEstablished");
}

@Override
public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
    call.close();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Call has been terminated");
    ServiceStatus status = getServiceStatus(call,
           call.getLocalProfile());
    SipPlugin.this.onSipEvent(status, "onCallEnded");
}
```

The following log is displayed when a call is established (incoming or outgoing calls) :

```
10-28 16:12:24.444: W/AudioGroup(28686): device loop timeout
```

And it is displayed multiple times. The audio is hashed on both ends of the call.

Comment: Hi, I have also had this problem, and have been looking into it for a long time now. I still have no solution to it, but some of my observations so far are: It only happens for me on Samsung devices; Not Nexuses. It also doesn't always happen every time.

Comment: Which device are you running on? I am trying to determine if this only affects Samsung devices. Thank you.

Comment: I was testing on a Samsung Device also. I have manage to jury rig the problem by having the call management in a remote service. The problem disapeared but i wish i hadn't have to do it because it makes the code much more complex...